# Why can't my function take in a char variable type?

Tags: c, pointers

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool isHex(char * str[20]){
    return isxdigit(str);
}

int main(){
    printf("%d\n", isHex("A8"));
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following message when I try to compile:

```
ishex.c:6:21: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'char **'
      to parameter of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    return isxdigit(str);
                    ^~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_ctype.h:280:14: note: 
      passing argument to parameter '_c' here
isxdigit(int _c)
             ^
ishex.c:13:26: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char [3]' to parameter
      of type 'char **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    printf("%d\n", isHex("A8"));
                         ^~~~
ishex.c:5:19: note: passing argument to parameter 'str' here
bool isHex(char * str[20]){
```

What is the issue in my code? I just want it to return `true` (`1`) if the string is a valid hex character, and `false` (`0`) if the string is not a valid hex character.

Comment: In your own words: what do you expect `char * str[20]` to mean - what words would you use to explain what the type of `str` is? Do you expect `"A8"` to be an instance of that type? Why?

Comment: `char *str[20]` means an array of 20 strings. `"A8"` is not an array of strings, it's just a single string.

Comment: Declare it just `char *str` or `char str[]`. You don't need to specify the size in an parameter declaration (you can do it, but it's ignored).

Comment: @Barmar `const char *` or `const char []` . const correctness should be learned from the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two problems.  First, your function as defined takes an array of `char` pointers and yet you're passing in a single `const char*`.  Second, `isxdigit` takes a single `char` and not an array of `char*`.  You should change your function to

```
bool isHex(const char *str)
{
    size_t len;

    if ( str == NULL ) { // In general, you need to protect your functions from bad arguments.
        return false;
    }

    len = strlen(str);
    for (size_t k=0; k<len; k++) {
        if ( !isxdigit(str[k]) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: 1. `len` has wrong type. 2. there is no need for `strlen` and to iterate again (strlen did it already). 3. not fully correct call to the isxdigit.

Comment: It is good to keep number of return statements as small as possible.

Comment: I don't follow you on 3).

Comment: functions with plenty of returns are hard to read and it is very easy to make silly mistakes.

Comment: I understand that but what's wrong with my use of `isxdigit`?

Comment: I did.  It returns a non-zero value on success.

Comment: read about parameters (I know it is very strict but it is good to give good example)

Comment: Done.  It takes an `int` which must either be `EOF` or representable as an `unsigned char`.  `str[k]`, which is a `char`, satisfies the second criterion.

Comment: @DanielWalker "... or representable as an `unsigned char`. `str[k]`, which is a `char`, satisfies the second criterion. " --> Not quite.  When `str[k] < 0`, it is not representable as an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty problems:

1. `char * str[20]` is the array of 20 pointers to char. Effectively it is `char **`
2. `isxdigit` checks only one char not the whole string. You need to iterate through all characters.

```
bool isHex(const char *str)
{
    bool result = str ? true : false;
    if(result)
    {
        while(*str)
            if(!isxdigit((unsigned char)*str++))
            {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void){
    printf("%d\n", isHex("A8"));
    return 0;
}
```